# Restart instance cassandra - commitlog, saved cache warnings?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm seeing these messages on node restart.  What do they mean?

```
INFO  [main] 2019-08-01 23:21:16,645 ViewManager.java:137 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system_traces as storage service is not initialized
INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] 2019-08-01 23:21:16,646 AutoSavingCache.java:198 - reading saved cache apache-cassandra-3.11.3/bin/../data/saved_caches/KeyCache-e.db
INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] 2019-08-01 23:21:16,678 AutoSavingCache.java:263 - Harmless error reading saved cache /home/cassadmin/apache-cassandra-3.11.3/bin/../data/saved_caches/KeyCache-e.db
INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] 2019-08-01 23:21:16,679 AutoSavingCache.java:174 - Completed loading (33 ms; 41 keys) KeyCache cache
INFO  [main] 2019-08-01 23:21:16,706 CommitLogReader.java:105 - Skipping playback of empty log: CommitLog-6-1557227264256.log
INFO  [main] 2019-08-01 23:21:17,360 CommitLog.java:159 - Log replay complete, 12 replayed mutations –
INFO  [main] 2019-08-01 23:21:17,364 StorageService.java:600 - Populating token metadata from system tables
```

Comment: So what is the problem actually? Can You elaborate on it with Your own words?

Comment: when you start the node confuses this message.

Comment: INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] 2019-08-01 23:21:16,679 AutoSavingCache.java:174 - Completed loading (33 ms; 41 keys) KeyCache cache

Comment: INFO  [main] 2019-08-01 23:21:16,706 CommitLogReader.java:105 - Skipping playback of empty log: CommitLog-6-1557227264256.log

Comment: INFO  [main] 2019-08-01 23:21:17,360 CommitLog.java:159 - Log replay complete, 12 replayed mutations

Comment: INFO  [main] 2019-08-01 23:21:17,364 StorageService.java:600 - Populating token metadata from system tables

Comment: INFO  [main] 2019-08-01 23:21:17,369 StorageService.java:607 - Token metadata: Normal Tokens:

Comment: What does this even mean?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you'll see messages like these in your system.log on startup.  By reading these messages, it appears (to me) that you've cleared the node's data, but didn't also wipe the `commitlog` and `saved_caches` directories.  At any rate, here's what they mean:

```
INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] 2019-08-01 23:21:16,646 AutoSavingCache.java:198 - reading saved cache apache-cassandra-3.11.3/bin/../data/saved_caches/KeyCache-e.db
INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] 2019-08-01 23:21:16,678 AutoSavingCache.java:263 - Harmless error reading saved cache /home/cassadmin/apache-cassandra-3.11.3/bin/../data/saved_caches/KeyCache-e.db
INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] 2019-08-01 23:21:16,679 AutoSavingCache.java:174 - Completed loading (33 ms; 41 keys) KeyCache cache
```

Cassandra checks the `saved_caches` dir at startup.  Basically, if you have key caching enabled (default) or row caching enabled, they do get persisted to disk.  This way they can be loaded at startup time, to get your key/row cache hot.

It is common to see errors on reading the `saved_caches` dir if its contents do not match what Cassandra has stored.

```
INFO  [main] 2019-08-01 23:21:16,706 CommitLogReader.java:105 - Skipping playback of empty log: CommitLog-6-1557227264256.log
INFO  [main] 2019-08-01 23:21:17,360 CommitLog.java:159 - Log replay complete, 12 replayed mutations –
```

At startup time, Cassandra also checks the commitlog.  This is a safety check to help ensure data durability.  When data is written, it's written both in RAM (memtable) and disk (commitlog).  If the node is shutdown unexpectedly and doesn't have a chance to flush the memtables to disk, there will be orphaned files entries in the `commitlog` dir.  These files are then read and reconciled with the data stored in the SSTables on disk.

If a node is shutdown abruptly, it is not uncommon to see corrupted or empty files in the `commitlog` dir, which will be flagged appropriately.

But basically, messages like these are merely informational, and do not necessarily indicate that anything is wrong with your node or cluster.

**Pro-tip:**  Cassandra 3.11.3 has a bug that can lead to corrupted data on a delete ([CASSANDRA-14672](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14672)).  You should upgrade to 3.11.4, where this is not an issue.